# Display Blob in JSP using img tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, jsp, blob

I want to build a webapp with user gallery (upload and display photos). In case of upload I'm using an DropZone.js plugin, and I guess it work's correctly. The problem is that, I can't display my photos on the website. I have no idea where the problem is.

Controller method code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "upload/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public GenericResponse uploadPhotos(MultipartHttpServletRequest request){
    try {
        Iterator<String> iterator = request.getFileNames();

    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        String uploadedFile = iterator.next();

        MultipartFile file = request.getFile(uploadedFile);

        String fileName = file.getOriginalFilename();
        String mimeType = file.getContentType();
        byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();

        Photo photo = new Photo(fileName, mimeType, bytes);

        userService.addNewPhoto(new Long(1), photo);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return new GenericResponse("success");
}
```

Photo Entity class:

```
public class Photo extends BaseEntity{

    @Lob
    private byte[] file;

    private String mimeType;

    private String fileName;

    public Photo() {

    }

    public Photo(String fileName, String mimeType, byte[] bytes) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.mimeType = mimeType;
        this.file = bytes;
    }

// getters, setters, etc.
}
```

Div inside *.jsp:

```
<div class="ui three column grid" id="galleryGrid">

  <jstl:forEach items="${photos}" var="photo">
    <div class="column">
      <div class="ui image segment">
          <div class="image">
            <img  alt="${photo.getFileName()}" src= "data:${photo.getMimeType()};bytes,${photo.getFile()}"/>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </jstl:forEach>

</div>
```

EDIT:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "Gallery/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showGallery(Model model, @PathVariable Long id){
    Collection<Photo> photos = userService.getGalleryPhotos(id);

    model.addAttribute("photos", photos);

    return "Gallery";
}
```

EDIT2:

[image]
Thank's for help.

Comment: I don't see the code where the `photos` variable is supposed to be set

Comment: Added, but it doesn't matter, because it's displaying photo's name in alt tag well.

Comment: OK, that wasn't mentioned in the original version. So basically you get a series of divs with imgs in it where `alt` is correctly filled, right? What does it show in `src= "data:` ? Does it look OK?

Comment: Yes, the alt is filled correctly. Problem is that, it doesn't display photos. I just get "no photo image".

Comment: So there is nothing behind "data"? If there is something, see [rfc2397](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2397): Without ";base64", the data (as a sequence of    octets) is represented using ASCII encoding for octets inside the range of safe URL characters and **using the standard %xx hex encoding of URLs for octets outside that range**.

Comment: I think your implementation of data uri's is incorrect - nowhere in the standard I see a mention of a literal field "bytes," followed by a raw set of byte values. Also, be aware that this is a pretty inefficient way of transporting images and that browsers tend to have fairly low limits on the size of data uris.